# Centering table caption between two columns

Tags: tables, captions

I want to center a table caption between the 5th and 6th columns, like this:

[image: target table]

where I've made the following

[image: current table attempt]

in this way:

```
% for table captions on top
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
% space out columns
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{14pt}
% remove default caption numbering
\usepackage{caption}

    \begin{table}[th!]
        \centering
        \caption*{$x_{2}$}
        \begin{tabular}{l c | c c c c c}
                    &   & 0   & 1    & 2    & 3    \\
            \hline
                    & 0 & .08 & .07 & .04 & .00 \\
                    & 1 & .06 & .15 & .05 & .04 \\
            $x_{1}$ & 2 & .05 & .04 & .10 & .06 \\
                    & 3 & .00 & .03 & .04 & .07 \\
                    & 4 & .00 & .01 & .05 & .06 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

where the `h!` is just for forcing the table's position in the document.

I've looked into `threeparttable`, but I didn't see anything in the (fairly brief) documentation that seemed like it would help.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the caption for labelling your columns. I would suggest you add an extra row with this code ```\ & \ & \ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x_2$} & \ &  \\``` above your data. It worked when I tried it in your code. `\multicolumn{}{}{}` merges columns in your table, 2 in this case. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [@nikjohn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/123723/nikjohn)'s comment:

> You shouldn't be using the caption for labelling your columns. I would suggest you add an extra row with this code `\ & \ & \ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x_2$} & \ & \\` above your data. It worked when I tried it in your code. `\multicolumn{}{}{}` merges columns in your table, 2 in this case.

The code using this:

```
\begin{table}[th!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c | c c c c }
        \ & \ & \ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x_2$} & \ \\
                &   & 0   & 1    & 2    & 3    \\
        \hline
                & 0 & .08 & .07 & .04 & .00 \\
                & 1 & .06 & .15 & .05 & .04 \\
        $x_{1}$ & 2 & .05 & .04 & .10 & .06 \\
                & 3 & .00 & .03 & .04 & .07 \\
                & 4 & .00 & .01 & .05 & .06 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and resultant image:

[image: result image]